# repeating one push message when trying to send new web push by php

Tags: php, web-push

i was interested in web push so i researched about that.
finally i could gather something that work and send web push to chrome.
the problem is, it just keep repeating one push message with the same title, same content,same photo!(i think is the first message i've sent).
ofcourse i guess it's more like a cache problem or what ever. what should i do?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);
function sendMessageGcm($registration_id,$message){             
  $key = "MY_KEY";
  $data = array(
    "registration_ids" => array($registration_id),
    "data" => array(
        'message' => $message,
    ),
);
  $headers = array(
    "Content-Type:application/json",
    "Authorization:key=" . $key,
  );
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  if($result == false) {
    echo('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
  }
  curl_close($ch);
  $rtn["code"] = "000";//means result OK
  $rtn["msg"] = "OK";
  $rtn["result"] = $result;
  return($rtn);
}
sendMessageGcm('ENDPOINT','hi there!');
?>
```

Comment: i searched more and i think it has something to do with payload. can it be relative?